# R series plot with groups

Tags: r, plot, series

I'm new at R. I have an csv file with 4 columns. One is the game name, the second one is the room its installed, the month and the last one is how many times it was played. Could you guys help me create a serie plot of how many times each game were played along the months ? Thank you!

data:

```
     game   Room    Month   Timesplayed
     A        IND         1         5
     A        FOR         1         6
     A        TYH         1         4
     B        IND         1         3
     B        FOR         1         2
     C        TYH         1         1
     C        IND         1         4
     E        IND         1         2
     E        FOR         1         1
     F        KUY         1         2
     F        TYH         1         5
     F        FOR         1         6
     F        IND         1         3
     A        IND         2         2
     A        FOR         2         1
     A        TYH         2         0
     B        IND         2         7
     B        FOR         2         10
     C        TYH         2         4
     C        IND         2         2
     E        IND         2         3
     E        FOR         2         5
     F        KUY         2         6
     F        TYH         2         7         
     F        FOR         2         2
     F        IND         2         1
     A        IND         3         9
     A        FOR         3         0
     A        TYH         3         3
     B        IND         3         4
     B        FOR         3         2
     C        TYH         3         1
     C        IND         3         7
     E        IND         3         9
     E        FOR         3         4
     F        KUY         3         3
     F        TYH         3         6
     F        FOR         3         2
     F        IND         3         2
```

I tryied plot.ts(percent2), but it shows Erro em plotts(x = x, y = y, plot.type = plot.type, xy.labels = xy.labels, : cannot plot more than 10 series as "multiple"

Comment: I tryied plot.ts(percent2), but it shows Erro em plotts(x = x, y = y, plot.type = plot.type, xy.labels = xy.labels,  : 
  cannot plot more than 10 series as "multiple"

Comment: Not without any data we can't.  Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data frame is `df` and using your columns "game, Month,  and Timesplayed", you can try `ggplot(df, aes(x = Month, y = Timesplayed, fill=game)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")`

More here: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_bar.html

Comment: `gplot(df, aes(x = Month, y = Timesplayed, colour=game, group=game)) + geom_line()`. You may need to make some adjustments to axis etc. See: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_line.html

Comment: In ggplot, it is preferred to make changes to the dataframe before plotting. So you could pass `df[game=="A",]`, for example. Another option is to plot each game seperately using `facet_wrap`: `ggplot(df, aes(x = Month, y = Timesplayed, colour=game, group=game)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~game)`